Is this nonlinearity in AD5292 expected?
I am using five AD5292 digital potentiometers at \$20k\Omega\$ for a little exercise in hybrid (analog+digital) computing. They are connected to an Arduino DUE via SPI to act as parameter potentiometers in voltage-splitter configuration. After I soldered everything together, I ran a test wherein I increased the wiper setting in equal increments from 0 to 1 analog computer "machine units" (scaled to [0, 1023] and rounded) and observed the results on the oscilloscope. In particular,

Terminal A: +10V or –10V
Terminal B: 0V
Terminal W to scope.
Dual supply: \$\pm 15V\$

After observing that the scope did not render a triangle wave, I took a sample of 20 values and put them into Mathematica to find a software correction for the wiper setting. The Mathematica plot shown is a faithful representation of what I see on the scope without the correction.
All five pots show the identical behavior, reproduced reliably over time, and supplying \$-10V\$ at Terminal A shows the corresponding symmetric curve.

This being my first interaction with this chip, is this what it is expected to be doing?

@Andyaka To show that I'm not at the rails with my inputs to Terminal A and B? I need dual supply because I (intend to) use the pots for AC signals.

Please show a schematic of how you connected things

@Andyaka With all due respect, but your question about "what the dual supply is all about" and your subsequently deleting that comment after I responded to it leads me to believe that you are not in a position to help me with a question about this product's general behavior, with or without schematics.
It's hooked up just like the spec sheet asks, and the Arduino talks to it without problem.

This will be a good question if you add the diagrams suggested and the link to the datasheet.  " It's hooked up just like the spec sheet asks" .. at SE.EE it's generally best for the original poster to put the diagram (cut and paste from the datasheet, if that's what's appropriate).  And even more so now that you found the explanation.

@jonathanjo The data sheet does not contain the answer, nor does the schematics (which contains the chip, the Arduino's SPI connector, and the analog computer with the hybrid connector, etc., all of which were hooked up correctly). The problem rested with the analog computer's oscilloscope X-output (specifically its input impedance), and in order to find that problem, you'd have to study the circuitry of that computer. Nothing I could have share with you would have contained more clues about the problem, but in hindsight, the dip in the voltage curve I did share does give a  good clue.

Respectfully, it's more a matter of helping people help you: put a link to the datasheet, so we know what you're looking at -- most readers won't even know how many pins this chip has, for example -- and asking people to think about circuits without a diagram is just unnecessary obfuscation.  You may know the diagram is incredibly simple, but you have seen it.

Well color me surprised -- that was not a problem I even considered: The distortion/nonlinear response arose only when I looked at the voltage at the wiper via my analog computer's output pin and from there to the scope.
Hooking up the scope probe directly to the pot's wiper: perfect triangle wave.
Hooking up the wiper to the input of an inverter on the analog computer (which I know has high input impedance because it's an op-amp) and then to the X-output hooked up to the scope: perfect triangle wave.
Well, I did not expect the output terminal of the analog computer to have low impedance. But in the ordinary cause of business, the wiper will always be connected to the input of some op-amp (summer, integrator, inverter, etc.), so it should be fine without installing an additional op-amp voltage follower.

This is why people ask you to draw a circuit.  Unexpected behavior is usually due to the connection between components rather than the components themselves.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@user1850479 This is a problem due to a component: the unexpectedly low input impedance of a connection (X-output) on the analog computer (The Analog Thing). It's the same connection one uses to look at the solution to a math problem on the oscilloscope, so there was no a-priori reason to expect its causing a voltage drop in the voltage divider.
All I was asking: Does this chip do this in the ordinary course of operation, and all I needed for a response was, "No, it definitely doesn't do that." I did not ask anyone to FIND the problem for me.
